# Jquery validation - errorPlacement only works first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

This is my code

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

```
var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.html("");
        var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
        img.attr('src', "../images/inputerror.png");
        img.appendTo(error);
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

This sets an image instead of the 'This field is required'.

It all works fine.. but only the first time.
When I validate it again, it shows 'this field is required again'.

---

first time

[image]

---

second time

[image]

Comment: please provide fiddle if possible.

Comment: if you're binding it to `pageinit`, use `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow` instead. `pageinit` fires once only. edit/tip: use unqiue `id` for elements.

Comment: @Omar I bind the validator everytime The login button is clicked.

Comment: @KenVernaillen can u make fiddle ?

Comment: @TusharGupta I can't get it to work in Fiddle (I never made a Fiddle)

Comment: you need to define override error message in `message` option. that's why it works the first time and then the default message overrides the custom one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WPbzN/

Comment: You have to use the proper callback functions to get the expected behavior. Typically, `errorPlacement` is only used for custom _layout_... like if you want all messages underneath the input or inside of a tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the proper callback functions to get the expected behavior.  Typically, `errorPlacement` is only used for custom *layout*... like if you want all messages underneath the input or inside of a tooltip.

For toggling classes on error, or toggling an image in this case, you would use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

However, your usage of HTML in place of the message is an acceptable workaround.  Just keep the DOM structure in mind... by default, your custom HTML will be wrapped inside of a `<label>` element unless you specify a different kind of element using the `errorElement` option.

DOM structure with default options:

```
<label class="error"><img src="inputerror.png" /></label>
```

Using the `errorElement: 'span'` option...

```
var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
    // your options and rules,
    errorElement: 'span'
});
```

Resulting DOM structure:

```
<span class="error"><img src="inputerror.png" /></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: "<img src='../images/inputerror.png'/>"
    });
```

This did it.
Thanks to @Omar!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just do it with showError function instead of errorReplacement?

Take a look at this example:

```
var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
    errorClass: "error", 
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents("div.control-group").addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
        $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass);
    }, 
    showErrors: function(map, list) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();           // calls the default function
                                            // after which we can add our changes
        $('span.error').each(function(index) {
            $(this).html('');
            var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
            img.attr('src', "../images/inputerror.png");
            $(this).append(img);            
        });
    }
});
```